# Descobrir se pessoas não compareceram

Tags: mysql

tenho uma tabela chamada armários que registro o numero do armario , nome do dono , e tenho outra tabela que registro a entrada dos alunos, porém se alguém que tenha armário falte por 10 dias preciso avisar, eu consigo trazer todo mundo que compareceu no periodo, como fazer para descobrir quem não compareceu ?

```
SELECT idcad,data_presenca FROM armario
INNER JOIN presenca ON armario.idcad = presenca.id_cad 
WHERE data_presenca BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE()-10 AND CURRENT_DATE()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente com subselect e not exists

```
SELECT armario.idcad 
FROM armario
Where not exists (select null
                  From presenca 
                  Where armario.idcad = presenca.id_cad 
                  And data_presenca > CURRENT_DATE()-10)
```

O select inferior verifica para um "idcad" quem teve presença nos últimos 10 dias , data maior que "hoje" menos 10 , o superior que não está neste grupo "Not" , ou seja os seus faltantes , gente que pelo visto perdeu o armário ... :)

Comment: Funcionou certinho, mas ainda tenho duvidas de como funciona o código, mas já me ajudou bastante e pesquiso aqui mais sobre o assunto, Muito obrigado !

Comment: Editei o texto , veja lá.

Comment: Amigo, apareceu um problema, esse código funcionou certinho até a vida do mês, porém agora ele não está considerando se o pessoal estava presente no mês passado, onde pode estar o problema ?

Comment: Não vejo pq pideria dar errado em viradas de mês. Tem um exemplo ?

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que entendi:

```
SELECT armario.idcad FROM armario
LEFT OUTER JOIN presenca ON armario.idcad = presenca.id_cad 
WHERE data_presenca < CURRENT_DATE()-10
```